# is smart gwt has performance issue for loading huge data from database?

Tags: internet-explorer, smartgwt, large-data

I am using smartgwt. When I tried to load huge data my explorer is not running & getting an error message that `"A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?"`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to load data into the databound components...
DataSource is quite powerful and is a good option when using very big data sets.

If you use a DataSource, make sure not to load the complete data in one request and let SmartGWT load the data on demand.
Also there are several options that can have an impact on performance on large datasets.

use dynamic loading:

```
myGrid.setLoadDataOnDemand(true); // good
```

do not use autofit rows as it requires to render all the rows:

```
listGrid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.BOTH); // bad, just let it on default
```

do not try to render all data at once:

```
grid.setShowAllRecords(true); // bad
```

and the last option: you simply created an endless loop ;-)